# Beauty is only skin deep

Tags: internal-consistency, society

Set in the early 22nd Century A.D. people desert plastic surgery in favor of a new cosmetic no incision solution to change their looks. They can change their look at their convenient no side effect no discomforts and result is instantaneous and permanent, the only downside is your family and friends may not recognize you at times. Assuming everyone can afford to alter their look unlimited times, especially those with crooked minds would definitely be pleased. What can the society do to prevent crimminal activities from becoming uncontrollable without banning people from altering their looks?

Answer (score 2):

Use means other than optical recognition for ID. A hundred years from now, there should be plenty of options.

- Everybody has an AI personal digital assistant with access to their digital wallet.
- Automated retina scans at door locks, etc.
- Reliance on forensics rather than eyewitness accounts.